# web data extractor

Tags: html, firefox

sometimes I see a table column in html on webpage and I would like to copy it, is there such tool/extension that allow me to do this?
for example, I need a table with 2 columns and I would to copy just the first column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer, yes, your mouse is the tool to use.

1) Highlight it (with your handy mouse) and either type Control + C or try right clicking and select copy.
2) paste it into excel / your spreadsheet program
3) remove the column you don't want.

Comment: Notepad++ offers vertical text selection. I think this is more what OP is after. However, I just tried your method with Excel and it did indeed work.

Comment: this would work too, I was thinking more of a one step utility, but whatever works.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a firefox add-ons [OutWit Hub](http://www.outwit.com/) It allows you to extract any web page information and export it to Excel Sheet.

there are many more softwares available on the internet for this purpose from which you can extract information (images, tables, data etc) from a web page.